# Joomla active page issue

Tags: joomla2.5

HI sorry I can't be more specific with my question heading,  but not sure how to describe my problem.  We have a website: www.octaviusephesus.com. I got someone to help me change the menu background picture (for example, click on "tour ideas /ephesus area" - ever since then the active pages all appear as if there is a layer of mesh over them - this wasn't there beforehand... I have asked the person who helped me to fix it,  because it seems to be connected with whatever was done to change the picture, but no success - can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hope i understood exact problem and help to you

Please check below css with line number 59

http://www.octaviusephesus.com/templates/theme1148/css/style1.css

image is coming from there if you can comment code and test it and small css fix will needed there.

Thanks